Why cannot my Azure Application Gateway connect to my Azure Container App?
I’m experiencing an issue when attempting to connect an Application Gateway to an Azure Container App. I have two gateways set up, both within the same VNet:
Gateway A: Successfully connects to the Container App.
Gateway B: Fails to connect, encountering a DNS resolution error.
I’m using Network Watcher for diagnostics, and when testing the connection from Gateway B, the error returned is Local Error: DNSResolution.
To rule out security group issues, I’ve ensured that the Network Security Groups (NSGs) for both Gateway B and the Container App Environment are wide open. Despite this, only Gateway A is able to resolve and connect to myapp.mydomain.com, which we’ve configured in our private DNS.
Both Application Gateways should theoretically resolve this domain and connect without issue, yet Gateway B consistently fails with the DNS resolution error.
Have I overlooked something, or is there a known issue that might cause this behavior?

Are the app gateways in different subnets?

@MoonHorse Hmm, in what way do you mean? I believe the only DNS configuration so far has been creating a private DNS record pointing myapp.mydomain.com to the IP address of the Container App Environment. Gateway A can resolve this whereas Gateway B is unable to resolve. (Note: the private DNS was linked to the VNet containing both Gateway A and Gateway B)

Where do you get this error message? In the probe configuration?

@MoonHorse I'm getting it in the Network Watcher > "Connection troubleshoot" tool.

@MoonHorse Yes, the app gateways are currently in different subnets (However, to rule out NSG issues, I disconnected the NSG for Gateway B's subnet)

Verify that the FQDN entered in the backend pool is correct and that it's a public domain, then try to resolve it from your local machine.
If you can resolve the IP address, there might be something wrong with the DNS configuration in the virtual network.
Check whether the virtual network is configured with a custom DNS server. If it is, check the DNS server about why it can't resolve to the IP address of the specified FQDN.
If you're using Azure default DNS, check with your domain name registrar about whether proper A record or CNAME record mapping has been completed.
If the domain is private or internal, try to resolve it from a VM in the same virtual network. If you can resolve it, restart Application Gateway and check again. To restart Application Gateway, you need to stop and start by using the PowerShell commands described in these linked resources.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#dns-resolution-error

I wouldn't think the backend pool is relevant when simply testing the connection using Network Watcher (e.g. I don't have a backend pool for this app configured on Gateway A, and yet I'm still able to test the connection via Network Watcher.
I had relatively high hopes around stopping/starting the AG; unfortunately, this didn't resolve the issue though.

I would suggest you to test by configuring the backend with the application gateway.

Ah, well, I'm trying. Unfortunately, I'm getting still getting 502 errors.

I faced the same issue and had to connect with the Azure team to get it resolved. Here is the solution:
If you are using an internal container app environment, you need to create a new Private DNS Zone for the container app you are trying to connect to.
Follow these steps:

Create a Private DNS Zone and name it as the FQDN of the Container App.
Go to Virtual Network Link under DNS Settings and add your VNet as a link.
Go to your Container App Environment and copy the IP from Custom DNS Suffix.
Go back to the Private DNS Zone, go to Record Sets under DNS Settings, and add two A records pointing to the Container App Environment IP: one should be named * and one @.

If the above steps are not valid for you, feel free to check out the accepted answer to this question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2072811/local-error-dnsresolution-in-application-gateway-w
